# (CGAL) How to determine if an edge is on border of a triangulation?

Tags: cgal, triangulation

I checked the CGAL mannual and didn't find such a method. So what should I do? Check if the edge is incident to infinite face? But edge in triangulation doesn't provide this method either.

Answer (score 0):

```
Triangulation_2 t;
Edge e;
Face_handle f = e.first;
int i = e.second;
if(f->has_vertex(t.infinite_vertex())) ||
   f->neighbor(i)->has_vertex(t.infinite_vertex()))){
   // on edge
}
```